# image display on mobile will not center

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, graphical-logo

I have this code for my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Navigation Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="desktop">
<a href="index.php">
<img border="0" class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" width="15%" height="20%" /></a> <font size="15%"><div class="BDtext">title<br> Description</font></div><br>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
<a href="index.php">
<img border="0" class="mobilogo" src="/images/logo.png" width="15%" height="20%" /></a>
</div>

    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li class="me"><a href="me.php">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="sessions"><a href="sessions.php">Sessions</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and this one in my style.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #ece8e5;
}

.logo{
float: left;
}

.BDtext {
text-align: center;
}


/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Menu */

#sub-header ul li:hover,
body.home li.home,
body.Ben li.Ben,
body.about li.about,
body.sessions li.sessions { background-color: #000;}            /* Current Page Background Colour */

nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #455868;                                    /* Menu Background Colour */
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;         /* Hover Over A Page Background Colour */
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav { 
  height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #283744;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
.desktop {display:none;}

.mobilogo{
margin-right: 45%;
width:50%;
height: 50%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 601px) {
.mobile {display:none;}
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}

/* End Menu */
```

my problem is.

my `.mobilogo` code in my CSS will not center the image.

I need this image to appear in the center of the page and not be aligned to the left.

please can someone help tell me what is holding it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.mobile class could have **text-align:center;** if you don't want to use the text-align try the below:

Also you can give .mobilogo width and have **margin:0 auto;** to center it.

```
.mobilogo{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

In order for the width and height to work with percentages you need to give the parent elements width and height.

Comment: this only moves the image over by at most 1 centimeter. there is something holding it back but i can not see what it is.

Comment: try to give mobilogo specific width and height in pixels to see if it works. Maybe the percentages that are not working right

Answer (score 1):

Make your `.mobilogo` class block and give it `margin: 0 auto` like this. Even though it has a width of 50% you'll have to make it a block element to center it with margin: 0 auto, or else you'll have to specify the width in pixels.

Like this:

```
.mobilogo {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block; 
}
```